# RedirectView makes session attributes gone

Tags: java, spring-mvc, session, http-redirect, httpsession

Im using RedirectView to redirect inside my SpringMVC application.

The problem is that before I return RedirectView I add one attribute to the session, but when redirect is done and the other servlet kicks in - session doesn't have that attribute I added before RedirectView. It seems that session attributes are cleaned up.

Does anybody know the reason?

```
@RequestMapping("/whatever")
public View myMethod(HttpSession session)
...
session.setAttribute("test", "testValue");
return RedirectView("/test");
```

---

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
public View testMethod(HttpSession session)
...
session.getAttribute("test")   // NULL HERE
return RedirectView("/finish");
```

Best regards.

Comment: You can use flash scoped attributes to ensure attributes are available in the 2nd controller after a redirect: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-flash-attribute-example/

Comment: It will work if u use return `redirect:/test`..and also once added to session will not clean up till you remove..or till expires..may be some configurations mistake or any annotation on class level?